# Python Pandas performing operation on each row of CSV file

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a 1million line CSV file. I want to do call a lookup function on each row's 1'st column, and append its result as a new column in the same CSV (if possible).

What I want is this is something like this:

```
for each row in dataframe
   string=row[1]
   result=lookupFunction(string)
   row.append[string]
```

I Know i could do it using python's CSV library by opening my CSV, read each row, do my operation, write results to a new CSV.

This is my code using Python's CSV library

```
with open(rawfile, 'r') as f:
    with open(newFile, 'a') as csvfile:
        csvwritter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
        for line in f: 
            #do operation
```

However I really want to do it with Pandas because it would be something new to me. 
This is what my data looks like

```
77,#oshkosh #         tannersville pa,,PA,US
82,#osithesakcom         ca,,CA,US
88,#osp open records        or,,OR,US
89,#ospbco      tel ord   in,,IN,US
98,#ospwmnwithn return    in,,IN,US
99,#ospwmnwithn tel ord   in,,IN,US
100,#osram sylvania inc      ma,,MA,US
106,#osteria giotto        montclair    nj,,NJ,US
```

Any help and guidance will be appreciated it. THanks

Comment: Please show us some of the code that you have written so far.

Comment: I added some code that I was using previously. I dont like that method though, it seems very primitive.  --Much thanks

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple example of adding 2 columns to a new column from you csv file

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("yourpath/yourfile.csv")

df['newcol'] = df['col1'] + df['col2']
```

Comment: Ok, my use case is a little bit more complicated than that.

My data are strings, and I need to do a google place API search on each string... then add the result as a column. How do I do that?

Much Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

***create `df` and `csv`***

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1, 2], B=[3, 4]))

df.to_csv('test_add_column.csv')
```

---

***read `csv` into `dfromcsv`***

```
dfromcsv = pd.read_csv('test_add_column.csv', index_col=0)
```

---

***create new column***

```
dfromcsv['C'] = df['A'] * df['B']
dfromcsv
```

[image]

---

***write csv***

```
dfromcsv.to_csv('test_add_column.csv')
```

---

***read it again***

```
dfromcsv2 = pd.read_csv('test_add_column.csv', index_col=0)

dfromcsv2
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, thats mathetmatical operation. 

What I want is to take the 1st column of each row, run it through my look up function, and append the result to the data frame. Is this possible??

THANKS

Comment: that's a different question.  You asked how to add a column in a csv using pandas.  I suggest choosing an answer for this question and asking a new question regarding the operation your talking about.  That operation has nothing to do with csv.